# How to save a person who has just fell down form an oceanic city?

Tags: science-fiction, ocean

So, my main characters, Bryan, Julia, and Logan have been visiting the city of Hydropolis, on the ocean planet of Aquatus V. The city overlooks the most beautiful sight under the sea, a 5,000 foot deep ocean trench.

Bryan is enthusiastic about seeing this trench, and looks over the guard rails a little too much. He falls down....down.....down...and down. He is so shocked by fear the he passes out. Luckily he is wearing an Aquatic suit that uses oxygen enriched fluid to breathe, instead of compressed gases, so he can survive a mile deep, for a little while. His friends contact the authorities to help save him.

How could you save a person that just fell down an oceanic trench?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Keith. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions about problems you are having while building your world. As is, this appears to be a question about solving a problem in your story, or defining the plot of your story, an issue outside the site's scope. If there are special constraints of your world that existing, real-world solutions cannot help with, then we would be happy to help design a device that meets your needs. As is, however, this is likely to be put on hold until an [edit] is made to bring it in scope.

Answer (score 1):

How can Byron fall 5,000 feet below the surface of the water?  Or is Hydropolis actually already underwater and beneath the surface?

in my experience most humans will naturally float to the surface of the water,  like most animals.

But if Byron's Aquatic suit weighs enough it might weigh him down enough to sink in the water.

5,000 feet down is about 1,524 meters.  In Earth's oceans the pressure of ocean water increases by one atmosphere every 10 meters down.  Of course on a different planet it is possible for the pressure increase to be slower - or faster. So 1,524 meters down on Earth, the pressure would be 152.4 Earth atmospheres, or overt 2,000 pounds per square inch of surface.  Diving just a few hundred feet down reaches depth where the water pressure makes the air humans breath so thick it becomes deadly poisonous.

And if Byron's Aquatic suit uses oxygen-rich fluids he might be able to survive at depths of one or two thousand feet.  But 5,000 feet?

So Byron probably can only survive 5,000 feet down if his Aquatic suit is a hard suit that doesn't compress.  It is easy to believe that such a hard suit could be heavy enough to keep Byron falling down through the water all the way to the bottom 5,000 feet down.

But if the hard suit is too heavy Byron will fall too fast and quite possibly be killed by the sudden deceleration when he hits the bottom.  And even if Byron isn't killed by the deceleration, the sudden stop might make even a tiny crack in Byron's hard suit.  And at 5,000 feet down in the ocean, even the tiniest crack in Byron's hard suit will be instantly fatal.

So perhaps you should get someone to compute a design for Byron's Aquatic suit that will keep him falling until he reaches the bottom 5,000 feet down, but falling slowly enough he isn't instantly killed by the landing, nor suffers even a tiny crack in his suit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to what you use when you want to rescue someone who is in trouble on the mountains.

On the mountains you use helicopters and rescue teams, in Acquatus you can use acquacopters, something similar to a 4 propellers drone, large enough to host the rescue team and the rescued.

If the Acquatic suit has some tracking device it will be easier to locate Bryan, else it would be quite a struggle to find someone who in unconscious in the darkness of the depth and half sunk into the mud covering the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the bottom of a 5000ft deep ocean trench under normal circumstances you'll need a really serious lighting grid all the way down, since sunlight will only penetrate the first 650ft or so of even the clearest water column in any meaningful way. That lighting system is going to need some routine maintenance regardless of how reliable it is. So to rescue someone who falls in you simply use the maintenance equipment to retrieve them.